# Passing dynamic values in XML

Tags: go

I have following xml file:

```
payload := []byte(strings.TrimSpace(`
<Login>
                <OverideLogging xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">0</OverideLogging>
                <Password xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">password</Password>
                <TransactionID xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">Id</TransactionID>
                <UserName xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">username</UserName>
            </Login>
`))
```

Now I have following data:

```
password:= "abc"
id:= 12
username:= "abc"
```

When I try to use this dynamic value, It say doesn't understand password field which should be taken from above constant.

if I use

```
payload := []byte(strings.TrimSpace(`
<Login>
                <OverideLogging xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">0</OverideLogging>
                <Password xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">abc</Password>
                <TransactionID xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">12</TransactionID>
                <UserName xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">abc</UserName>
            </Login>
`))
```

```
fmt.Println(payload)
```

It works perfectly.

Now If I want to pass dynamic value like below:

```
payload := []byte(strings.TrimSpace(`
<Login>
                <OverideLogging xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">0</OverideLogging>
                <Password xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">password</Password>
                <TransactionID xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">Id</TransactionID>
                <UserName xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">username</UserName>
            </Login>
`))

fmt.Println(payload)
```

Then It gives error as following:

```
password declared but not used
Id declared but not used
username declared but not used
```

I want to pass these values in xml body dynamically.
How do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: What says it doesn't understand the password field?

The code you've included doesn't do anything. Please show actual code, and your actual error messages.

Comment: I doesn't take password passed dynamically from the above declaration password:= "abc". It shows unused password:="abc"

Comment: WHAT doesn't take that? Please read my entire comment, and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go does not have that kind of [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). Variables will NOT be automatically injected into a string. You need to do it explicitly with plain concatenation or using the `fmt` package.

```golang
password := "abc"
id := 12
username := "abc"

payload := fmt.Sprintf(`<Login>
<OverideLogging xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">0</OverideLogging>
<Password xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">%s</Password>
<TransactionID xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">%d</TransactionID>
<UserName xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">%s</UserName>
</Login>`,
    password, // will replace the first verb (%s)
    id,       // will replace the second verb (%d)
    username, // will replace the third verb (%s)
)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/mdO8UvmZyD2

See the [`fmt` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt@go1.17.5) for more info on how the verbs work.

Comment: This looks good but what about if we have condition where we have to loop(range) the xml with different values inside.

Comment: @dev When you need to construct a more complex string it is often better to use templates. Templates do support loops and if conditions and what not. See [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template@go1.17.5). Also note that Go's standard library has an [`encoding/xml`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.17.5) package that can be used to generate valid XML from struct values, which can be even easier than templates.

Answer (score -1):

```
type Login struct {
    Password      string `xml:"Password"`
    UserName      string `xml:"UserName"`
    TransactionID string `xml:"TransactionID"`
}

func populateLogin() *Login {
    req := Login{}
    req.UserName = "abc"
    req.Password = "123"
    req.TransactionID = 23323
    return &req
}

func main(){

payload := []byte(`
                <Password xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">{{.Password}}</Password>
                <TransactionID xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">{{.TransactionID}}</TransactionID>
                <UserName xmlns="HitchHiker.FlightAPI.SharedStructs">{{.UserName}}</UserName>
            </Login>`)

login := populateLogin()

    template, _ := template.New("login").Parse(string(payload))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = template.Execute(os.Stdout, login)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This code works exactly. This can help if anyone is looking for answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)